# ChessBase: how to efficiently use two reference database simultaneously

Tags: software, database, chessbase, correspondence-chess

In ChessBase I use the Mega Database as my reference database when in a board. However, I recently downloaded a Correspondence database and would like to look up positions in it as well. Is there a way I can easily use both reference databases when in a board?

So far what I'm doing is keeping the Mega Database as my default Reference, and for the Correspondence Database I: right click on it --> click opening reference --> and another board pops up where I can look up things in it. However, this is a bit inconvenient since I must keep tabbing between the two boards and manually making the same moves on each of them.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way I can easily use both reference databases when in a
>   board?

The obvious way is to create a new database by merging MegaBase and your correspondence database and use this new database as your reference database.

Comment: I thought of that but I want the databases to be separate. Correspondence games are of a higher quality but Megabase games show which moves are popular in OTB.